# Cannot override styles with styled component in react-phone-input-2

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Styles can be overridden with additional CSS file imported but not with the styled component. Why?

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";

import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";
import "react-phone-input-2/lib/style.css";

const Phone = styled(PhoneInput)`
  #phone-input {
    background: red !important;
  }
`;

function InputMobile({value}) {
  function change(value) {
     ...
  }
  return (
    <Phone
      country={"us"}
      inputProps={{
        id: "phone-input"
      }}
      value={value}
      onChange={change}
    />
  );
}
export default InputMobile;
```

Such properties as dropdownStyle, inputStyle are not enough for me as I also need to style .arrow in .selected-flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `styled-component` with custom component you need to wrap it. Example:

```
const Wrapper = ({ className, ...props }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    <PhoneInput {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

You can test it live:

[image: Edit beautiful-bird-j00cr]

Answer (score 1):

for me this works properly.

in styles:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2";

export const StyledPhoneInput2 = styled(PhoneInput)`
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
`
```

also look in browser for inner classes and overwrite them if you need:

```
export const StyledPhoneInput2 = styled(PhoneInput)`
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
    
  &.react-tel-input .form-control {}
              
  &.react-tel-input .flag-dropdown {} 
`
```

then use it in component:

```
import { StyledPhoneInput } from "./your-name.styles";

<StyledPhoneInput/>
```